# Can you use relative paths when registering handlers in web.config

Tags: asp.net

I need to register a httphandler in a sub folder ("myTest") to my web application. 
I know that a solution would be to add a webconfig to the myTest folder, but that is not an option in this case.

I would like to add the following to my web.config (focus on the path attribute)

```
<system.webServer>
 <handlers>
  <add name="myHandler" verb="*" path="myTest/myHandler.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="xxxxxx.xxxx, xxxxxx" />
 </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

IIS 7 doesn't complain about the relative path, but it doesn't work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option would be to just place and .ashx file in the folder. Then you don't need to register anything in web.config.

Answer (score 0):

The path attribute shouldn't point to the handler itself, but specify the paths affected by that handler. So in your case:

```
<add name="myHandler" verb="*" path="/myTest/*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="YourHandlerAssembly.YourHandler, YourHandlerAssembly" />
```

Should pass all files in the `myTest` subfolder to your HttpHandler.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Just can't seem to get et working using path="/myTest/*"